# How to integrate $\int 2xe^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)- 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy) \ \mathrm dy$?

Tags: integration

Find the value of:
$$\int 2xe^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)- 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy) \ \mathrm dy$$

i have tried using integration by parts but it doesn't seem to work. How would I go about this integral ?

Comment: Is this the original exercise?

Comment: Knowing the domain of integration might prove helpful.

Comment: It is integration with respect to y

Comment: As much as I hate $\mathrm d$ vs. $d$, rolling back Parcly's edit because it completely changed the question.  We can't know for certain if OP meant what OP originally typed (a single integral for $dy$) or if OP meant what Parcly edited (a double integral with $dx \, dy$).  Requesting clarification from OP.

Comment: Well, that settles that then.

Comment: @aprilanalysis, is this really also an indefinite integral?

Comment: @tilper yes it is an indefinite integral

Comment: WolframAlpha tells us the [answer is $e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)+C$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+2xe%5E(x%5E2-y%5E2)cos(2xy)-2ye%5E(x%5E2-y%5E2)sin(2xy)dy), does this help?

Answer (score 3):

Since

$$  \frac{d}{dy}\left[e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)\right]=- 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)+2xe^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)$$

then

$$ \int 2xe^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)- 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)\,dy= e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)+c$$

Note: Because of the fact that the integrand appeared to be the result of application of the product rule for derivatives, it seemed appropriate to investigate the possibility.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \left(2xe^{x^2-y^2}\cos 2xy - 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin 2xy\right) \, dy = \int 2xe^{x^2-y^2} \cos 2xy \, dy - \int 2ye^{x^2-y^2} \sin 2xy \, dy $$

Let's integrate that first one on the RHS by parts.  We'll take $u = e^{x^2-y^2}$.  So then $du = -2ye^{x^2-y^2} \, dy$, $dv = 2x \cos 2xy \, dy$, and $v = \sin 2xy$.  (It may not be clear at first, but note that $v$ can easily be obtained from $dv$ with a simple substitution integral.  Substitute $t = 2xy$ into $\int 2x \cos 2xy \, dy$ to get $v = \sin 2xy$.)

With integration by parts, we have
\begin{align*}
  \int 2xe^{x^2-y^2} \cos2xy \, dy &= e^{x^2-y^2}\sin 2xy - \int \sin (2xy) \cdot \left(-2y e^{x^2-y^2}\right) \, dy\\[0.3cm]
    &= e^{x^2-y^2}\sin 2xy + \int 2y e^{x^2-y^2} \sin 2xy \, dy\\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}

Now use this with the very first line of my post to get a great cancellation, giving you the desired result immediately.